# Mirroring pub.dev packages to a custom package repository

Tags: flutter, dart, package, repository

As of Dart 2.15, you can create your own package repository.
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/custom-package-repositories#publishing-to-a-custom-package-repository

We need to mirror the subset of pub.dev packages (for corporative security reasons).
But there's no information, how to do a package mirroring.
Should I fork a GitHub source and publish every allowed package versions manually? It looks exremely annoying and time-consuming. And what about transitive dependencies? Should I upload all of them too?

I also found this article: https://medium.com/dartlang/hosting-a-private-dart-package-repository-774c3c51dff9 , it describes the pub.dev mirroring scenario too, but doesn't explains how to do it.

Comment: An even easier approach might be: https://github.com/tuna/pub-mirror

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer you are looking for, but I believe that with some experimentation this could be scripted using the APIs described in the dart package repository specification:

> https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/blob/master/doc/repository-spec-v2.md

For example, you can query all versions of a package like so:

```bash
curl https://pub.dev/api/packages/test 

{
            "version": "1.23.1",
            "pubspec": {
                "name": "test",
                "version": "1.23.1",
                ...
                "dependencies": {
                    "analyzer": ">=2.0.0 <6.0.0",
                    ...
                    "test_core": "0.4.24"
                },
                "dev_dependencies": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "archive_url": "https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test/versions/1.23.1.tar.gz",
            ...
        }
....
}
```

You can then use the `archive_url` for the version(s) you want to download the package, potentially iterating over the dependencies and downloading them as well.

You would then need to upload each package version you downloaded to your private repo. This can be done by first doing a GET on the new package submission URL:

```
curl https://my-private-repo.tld/api/packages/versions/new

{
    "url": "https://my-private-repo.tld/api/packages/versions/newUpload",
    "fields": {}
}
```

And then POST the form described by `fields` plus the archive you previously downloaded to the url provided in the response. Note that when I test this against [unpub](https://pub.dev/packages/unpub), the `fields` map is empty, but depending on your private repo implementation that may be different.

One could imagine a script that starts with a list of packages to mirror, downloads them, potentially also downloads their dependencies, and then uploads them all to the private server.

For transitive dependencies it probably depends on your security requirements. If you use `PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://my-private-repo.tld` then running `flutter pub get` will download any dependencies it can find from your private repo, and any other dependencies from pub.dev. If that is not acceptable, then you'll probably need to upload them all.